# Wildly with Hibernate 6 - mariadb dialect

Tags: hibernate, mariadb

In our WildFly based application, we are using mariadb-10.5.8 and mysql-connector as the driver. From the documentation, it appears that mariadb-10.5 is compatible with mysql-5.7

ORM we use is hibernate-6.2 and the documentation says MySQL-5.7 or higher and MariaDB-10.3 or higher are supported with out-of-box dialects. So the mariadb we use should be compatible

However, when we start our app, we see a WARNING message:

> "The 5.5.0 version for [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect] is no
> longer supported, hence certain features may not work properly. The
> minimum supported version is 5.7.0. Check the community dialects project for available legacy versions"

We looked at the connection meta-data returned from maria-DB. It returns "MySQL" as the product-name and  "5.5.5-10.5.8-MariaDB" as the product version. That seems to be the reason, hibernate is complaining. If we connect with the mariadb-driver, it return "MariaDB" as the product name and "10.5.8-MariaDB" as the version. But we are bit reluctant to change the driver due to any potential breakage/regression.

Few questions:

- What does the 5.5.0 prefix signify in the version string returned by DB when
  mysql-connector is used as the driver? Is it the compatible MySQL version? If so,
  why its not 5.7 as it appears from documentation that mariadb-10.2 is
  compatible with mysql-5.7?
- Is this WARNING a false alarm due to false detection of version or is something we should be concerned about? What will be implication if we leave it as is?
- If this needs to be addressed, What would be the best course of action:

  1. If we change the driver from mysql-connect to mariadb driver, what are the potential impacts considering it has been running with mysql-connector for many years now?
  2. Should we specifically set the dialect to one of the community dialect that matches our DB version?

Comment: Very simple: if you use mariadb, then you should use mariadb driver as mariadb is not mysql contrary to many belief. Compatibiloty means binary compatibility, so the communication protocol is the same, but the two products under the hood differ a lot.

Comment: Note also while upgrading and testing to a connected developed and tested with MariaDB, MariaDB-10.5 has had 3 years of bug fixes so far [since 10.5.8](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/release-notes-mariadb-105-series/).

Comment: Thanks @Shadow. Yes, we want to eventually go with the native driver

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

I had posted this question in mariadb discussion forum and got a response from mariadb eng team. Summary of the response is:

The prefix 5.5.5 to the version was added in mariadb-10.0 to make replication with MySQL slave work, as MySQL was detecting 10.x as 1.x. Native driver removes this prefix, so that returns proper version. This prefix has been removed from the newer mariadb releases

To cater to the automatic selection of dialect in hibernate, one of the following can be considered...

- Use native connector ([MariaDB Connector/J](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-connector-j/))
- Use newer MariaDB ([11.0+](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-28910))
- Add appropriate version string to my.cnf [version](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#version)=10.5.8-MariaDB